# Python Pygame падение объекта

Tags: python, pygame

Я бы хотел, чтобы у меня в игре в случайном месте появлялся метеорит и падал вниз, создавая проблемы игроку.

Я загрузил картинку метеора

```
meteor = pygame.image.load('met.jpg')
```

прописал координаты метеора вначале

```
x_met = random.randint(0, 900)
y_met = 0
```

а дальше создал функцию, которую вызываю внутри цикла:

```
def drawWindow2():
    global y_met

    win.blit(meteor, (x_met, 0))
    while y_met != 300:
        if x_met >= 0:
            y_met += 10
            win.blit(meteor, (x_met, y_met))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Метеорит мигает (как будто пытается сдвинутся, но ему мешают), но не двигается с места. Что я упустил?

Comment: покажите как вы вызываете эту функцию ? добавьте подробностей. по описанию похоже что вы каждый тик делаете по метеориту. #используйте кнопку править под вашим вопросом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Pygame есть основной цикл в котором и происходят все события. До смены кадра достаточно переместить ваш метеорит на какое-то расстояние, например y_met += 10, но если вы внутри основного цикла запускаете еще один, который гораздо быстрее, то метеорит "пролетает" весь экран без прорисовки. Вам просто надо убрать цикл while y_met != 300:. Ну и конечно убрать рекурсивный вызов функции.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Я и представить не мог что ошибка такая простая